# Retrieve multiple products by custom attribute [magento]

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a custom attribute for the products, and lets say I have 3-4 products that have the same value on that attribute. So, now I want to load these 3 products and store them in an array. Here's what I do:

```
$all_products = array();
$count = 0;
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('ordernumber');
foreach($collection as $product)
{
    $all_products[count] = array ('sku' => $product->getSku(), 'qty' => $this->getRequest()->get('qty'), 'size' => $product->getSize());
    $count++;
}
return $all_products;
```

Note: `ordernumber` HAS a value, I just get it from another place.

Anyway, when I run it - I have no values. When I debug - the debugger terminates at `$products[count] = ...`.

I tried loading a single product just by the custom attribute - `Mage::...->loadByAttribute('ordernumber', $ordernumber);` and it worked fine.

So, my guess is that I am not doing something correctly with the collection manipulation, or with the array, although, I saw some examples where I got the idea from.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$all_products = array();
$count = 0;
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('ordernumber');
//add a filter if needed - uncomment the next 2 lines and adjust the value or $ordernumber
//$ordernumber = '123';
//$addAttributeToFilter('ordernumber', $ordernumber)

foreach($collection as $product)
{
    $all_products[$count] = array ('sku' => $product->getSku(), 'qty' => $this->getRequest()->get('qty'), 'size' => $product->getSize());
    $count++;
}
return $all_products;
```